# ASP.NET Core slow HTTP requests to Azure App Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I've got a ASP.NET Core middleware that calls another HTTP service to check if user is authorized to proceed with request or not. At the moment it depends on a provided custom header, called `X-Parameter-Id`.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ParameterAuthorization.Middleware
{
    public class ParameterAuthorizationMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly IParameterAuthorizationService _parameterAuthorizationService;

        public ParameterAuthorizationMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, IParameterAuthorizationService parameterAuthorizationService)
        {
            _next = next ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(next));
            _parameterAuthorizationService = parameterAuthorizationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameterAuthorizationService));
        }

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (httpContext is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpContext));
            }

            if (parameterRequestContext is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(parameterRequestContext));
            }

            if (!(httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Parameter-Id") && httpContext.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization")))
            {
                await ForbiddenResponseAsync(httpContext);
            }

            var parameterIdHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Parameter-Id"].ToString();

            if (!int.TryParse(parameterIdHeader, out var parameterId) || parameterId < 1)
            {
                await ForbiddenResponseAsync(httpContext);
            }

            var authorizationHeader = httpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

            var parameterResponse = await _parameterAuthorizationService.AuthorizeUserParameterAsync(parameterId, authorizationHeader);

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterResponse))
            {
                await ForbiddenResponseAsync(httpContext);
            }

            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }

        private static async Task ForbiddenResponseAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status403Forbidden;
            await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the HTTP call implementation:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ParameterAuthorization.Middleware.Http
{
    public class ParameterAuthorizationService : IParameterAuthorizationService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly JsonSerializer _jsonSerializer;

        public ParameterAuthorizationService(HttpClient httpClient, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
            _jsonSerializer = jsonSerializer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(jsonSerializer));
        }

        public async Task<string> AuthorizeUserParameterAsync(int parameterId, string authorizationHeader)
        {
            var request = CreateRequest(parameterId, authorizationHeader);

            var result = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead);

            if (!result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            using (var responseStream = await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(streamReader))
            {
                return _jsonSerializer.Deserialize<ParameterResponse>(jsonTextReader).StringImInterestedIn;
            }
        }

        private static HttpRequestMessage CreateRequest(int parameterId, string authorizationHead1er)
        {
            var parameterUri = new Uri($"parameters/{parameterId}", UriKind.Relative);

            var message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, parameterUri);

            message.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHead1er);

            return message;
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the boilerplate code to DI named HttpClient

```
sc.TryAddSingleton<JsonSerializer>();
sc.AddHttpClient<IParameterAuthorizationService, ParameterAuthorizationService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = authorizationServiceUri;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
});
```

`authorizationServiceUri` is something I provide from a custom extension method.

The issue is that my calls to this service will randomly take 7, 10, even 20 seconds to this service and then it's going to be quick and then again slow. I call this exact `ParameterAuthorizationService` from Postman, it takes less than 50ms, constantly.

I'm attaching a screenshot from Application Insights showing the whole sequence of events.

[image: Application Insights performance log]

Both services are deployed as Azure App Services under the same subscription within the same App Service Plan.

Code works just fine, but I'm already pulling my hair off having no clue what could be causing these performance abnormalities.

I've also checked TCP Connections in Azure App service and it's all green.

[image: TCP Connections]

What could be the reason that some HTTP calls will be really slow?

#### Update

My App Service runs on a S1 App Service Plan. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/

Comment: Do you call your other app service frequently? If you don't it may be cold on the hosting VM and startup takes a while usually.

Comment: Are they throttling you?

Comment: No, however my other service has `Always On` turned on. Also it _feels_ really random, let's say I call the service and it takes 20 seconds to respond, some subsequent requests will be fast, a minute or few minutes later it'll be slow again.

Comment: @PmanAce they shouldn't, it's under development subscription, so it isn't really used actively, just by 5 developers. I yet have to try to run it against local service instead of a hosted on Azure.

Comment: Did you log the startup? Maybe its restarting due to crashes.

Comment: Do you have logs with the duration of inbound requests on the service? If so, does it match the time from the client perspective?

Comment: I do have logs of the other service and I'll check these tomorrow. Good suggestion, thank you. I'll also check if startup does not crash as well.

Comment: @Stefan I saw there are some exceptions, such as `StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.`, could this be related?

Comment: First of all I am not sure if it's related. On the other hand, it should be addressed as well. This usually happens when there already being written to the response stream. It might be the `await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Forbidden");` but I am not sure.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders have checked logs, they seem to match. They are under 100ms and, same as in the graph above.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas What if the used library has a performance problem or there is a bug? Just for testing purpose, didnt you think to test another implementation of Http communication, i.e.  RestSharp?

Comment: @Arsiwaldi I actually haven't tried it out, thanks for suggestion. I'll also inspect app with Stackify Prefix and see what's actually bottlenecking and causing most time to execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should short circuit the pipeline if you write to httpContent. See [Aspnet Core Middleware documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

> Don't call next.Invoke after the response has been sent to the client.

Use something like this :

```cs
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parameterResponse))
{
    await ForbiddenResponseAsync(httpContext);
}
else
{
    await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
}
```

Consider also handling authentification with a middleware that inherit from the aspnet core [AuthenticationHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.authenticationhandler-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) class to leverage all the aspnet core Authentification/Authorization facilities. Here is an implementation example of a [BasicAuthentification handler](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/09/08/aspnet-core-21-basic-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api) for simplicity.

Your ParameterAuthorizationService looks good. I don't think it's the source of your slow request call. To be sure, you can [track the entire service call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies) by measuring the time it takes and publishing-it in appinsights :

```cs
public class ParameterAuthorizationService : IParameterAuthorizationService
{
    //...

    private readonly TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

    public ParameterAuthorizationService(HttpClient httpClient, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
    {
        //...

        _telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
    }

    public async Task<string> AuthorizeUserParameterAsync(int parameterId, string authorizationHeader)
    {
        var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var timer = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var isSuccess = true;

        try
        {
            return await AuthorizeUserParameterImpl(parameterId, authorizationHeader);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            timer.Stop();
            isSuccess = false;

            _telemetryClient.TrackException(ex);
            _telemetryClient.TrackDependency("Http", nameof(ParameterAuthorizationService), nameof(AuthorizeUserParameterAsync),
                startTime, timer.Elapsed, isSuccess);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (timer.IsRunning)
                timer.Stop();
            if (isSuccess)
                _telemetryClient.TrackDependency(
                "Http", nameof(ParameterAuthorizationService), nameof(AuthorizeUserParameterAsync),
                startTime, timer.Elapsed, isSuccess);
        }                
    }

    private async Task<string> AuthorizeUserParameterImpl(int parameterId, string authorizationHeader)
    {
        //Your original code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have found where your trouble might be, taken from [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/performance-best-practices?view=aspnetcore-2.2):

> Although `HttpClient` implements the `IDisposable` interface, it's
>   designed for reuse. Closed `HttpClient` instances leave sockets open in
>   the TIME_WAIT state for a short period of time. If a code path that
>   creates and disposes of `HttpClient` objects is frequently used, the app
>   may exhaust available sockets. `HttpClientFactory` was introduced in
>   ASP.NET Core 2.1 as a solution to this problem. It handles pooling
>   HTTP connections to optimize performance and reliability.
>
> Recommendations:
>
> - Do not create and dispose of HttpClient instances directly.
> - Do use HttpClientFactory to retrieve HttpClient instances. For more    information, see Use HttpClientFactory to implement resilient HTTP
>     requests.

I can see you are using `HttpClient` in your code, which might hint where you should focus your performance solution.

You tagged asp.net core 2.2 in the question, So I do recommend you use [HttpClientFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) instead of `HttpClient` in your code, as suggested.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, like @MarkusDresch said, I already use HttpClientFactory :/